# Missing 'Generate' button in Rigify Buttons tab

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

[image: missing generate button]

I cannot find the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button to generate my rig, in the Blender Cookie Rigging Tutorial it should be found in the bottom right corner as another tab under the "Rigify Buttons" tab.

However I cannot see the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button under the Rigify Buttons tab. I can only see an add sample button.

[image: Tutorial Screenshot]

You can see the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button in the bottom right corner of the screen clipping from the Youtube tutorial, but not on my screen.

Answer (score 5):

The Generate Button is only available in *Object Mode*. The screenshot you posted shows that you're in *Edit Mode* Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then the button should appear.